# Juce - setLookAndFeel - error

Tags: xcode, slider, juce

I work with Projucer (Juce v5.2.0) and xCode 9.2 and I have some strange error when I use setLookAndFeel on Slider.

I go step by step with that tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=po46y8UKPOY&t=1020s

And I make exactly the same code. On the video there is no problem. My error appear when I compile the same code as it's in the 17:13 duration of the movie.

My problem is: when I compile the code everything is OK, my compiled app works great, "setLookAndFeel" works as expect. But the problem is when I close app. Then app looks like closed, but the icon is on the dock, and xCode shows "Stop" button active, so it looks like my app still works in some way. And xCode takes me automatically to something called "Juce Massage Thread (1)" and there is error:
`Juce Message Thread (1): EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0`

It's next to that code:

```
jassert (masterReference.getNumActiveWeakReferences() == 0
          || (masterReference.getNumActiveWeakReferences() == 1
               && this == &getDefaultLookAndFeel()));
```

Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There's a large comment block above the assertion that you've hit explaining why you have hit it:

```
/* This assertion is triggered if you try to delete a LookAndFeel object while something
   is still using it!

   Reasons may be:
     - it's still being used as the default LookAndFeel; or
     - it's set as a Component's current lookandfeel; or
     - there's a WeakReference to it somewhere else in your code

   Generally the fix for this will be to make sure you call
   Component::setLookandFeel (nullptr) on any components that were still using
   it before you delete it, or call LookAndFeel::setDefaultLookAndFeel (nullptr)
   if you had set it up to be the default one. This assertion can also be avoided by
   declaring your LookAndFeel object before any of the Components that use it as
   the LookAndFeel will be destroyed before the Components.

   Deleting a LookAndFeel is unlikely to cause a crash since most things will use a
   safe WeakReference to it, but it could cause some unexpected graphical behaviour,
   so it's advisable to clear up any references before destroying them!
*/
```

So you need to call `setLookAndFeel (nullptr)` on your slider before it is deleted, probably in the destructor of its parent component.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me.